# Call the other package's activity in the Preference

Tags: android

I add new class in the android/packages/apps/phone/src and I want to call the class in the ohter application.

Assume that the new class is SS.java
I added

```
<activity android:name="SS"></activity>
```

in the AndroidManifest.xml file in the android/packages/apps/phone folder.

The application which want to call the SS class has a list and I put the code in the xml file;

```
<PreferenceScreen
   android:title="@string/SS">
   <intent
        android:action="android.intent.action.MAIN"
        android:targetPackage="com.android.phone"
        android:targetClass="com.android.phone.SS" />
```

When I choose the menu in the list, the phone show Class Not Found Exception.
The message isUnable to find explicit activity class {com.android.phone/com/android.phone.SS}; ....

Please let mw know what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about contributing to the AOSP or building custom ROMs? If you are, this is not the most relevant forum. Try http://groups.google.com/group/android-contrib?pli=1.

If you are not, then:

The `android/packages/apps/phone` is a part of special apps shipped with the OS. You can't add classes to this package. Even if you do and compile the AOSP code, no phone will have your classes, so no application can use your classes.